# numpy MaskedConstant gives inconsistent conversion to bool

Tags: python, numpy

In Numpy Python, 1.8.0:

It seems that when working with aggregate functions (min,max) over masked arrays the potential for the result to be a MaskedConstant can cause real headaches. This is made much more dangerously fragile by the following odd behavior.

```
import numpy
testC = numpy.ma.masked_array([1,2],[True,True]).min()
print type(testC) # -> <class 'numpy.ma.core.MaskedConstant'> 
print bool((testC==None)) # -> False 
print bool((testC!=None)) # -> False (???)
```

I would hate to use isinstance or something, since I feel like that would couple to this kind of internal type class (I think). I can make a test work, by being careful to test for !=, since then any other valid number should pass. But I feel it's dangerous since the logic should be correct if inverted and given this behavior it's not.

I am trying to safely accumulate min over many distinct ma's. I cannot load them all, I need to combine results from the partial aggregations. It is in this combination that I stumbled over this.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the value returned by `numpy.ma.masked_array([1,2], [True,True]).min()` is `masked` (i.e. `numpy.ma.masked`, an instance of `numpy.ma.core.MaskedConstant`).  This is how the numpy masked array code handles the attempt to find the minimum of what is, in effect, an empty set.  Compare that to how a regular numpy array behaves:

```
In [36]: np.array([]).min()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-a63f9cff1d67> in <module>()
----> 1 np.array([]).min()
...<snip>...

ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity
```

The `__eq__` method of the `MaskedConstant` class returns `masked` if the instance (i.e. `self`) is `masked`, no matter what the other argument is.  In other words, `masked == <anything else here>` returns `masked`.  For example,

```
In [28]: from numpy.ma import masked

In [29]: type(masked)
Out[29]: numpy.ma.core.MaskedConstant

In [30]: masked == 99
Out[30]: masked

In [31]: masked == [1, 2, 3]
Out[31]: masked

In [32]: masked == masked
Out[32]: masked
```

To test for this value, you can use `is`:

```
In [33]: masked is masked
Out[33]: True

In [34]: masked is 99
Out[34]: False

In [35]: masked is None
Out[35]: False
```

In your code, you can test the return value of the `min` method with `testC is masked`.  When this occurs, it means all the values in this batch are masked, so this batch has no effect on the aggregated minimum of all your masked arrays.

Comment: I will certainly change tests to 'is masked' for the clear clarity that provides. It still bothers me that equivalence is defined in such a universal manner. Masked seems more like a nothing concept than an everything!